# Is there an debian/ubuntu package containing mdframed.sty?

Tags: texlive, ubuntu, mdframed

I found several answers on this site recommending the mdframed package. However, I can't find a ubuntu texlive package that includes this. Do I have to install this manually or am I overlooking something here?

Comment: the package is included in TeXLive. Try `tlmgr install mdframed`

Comment: @Macro: The TeXLive which comes with Ubuntu doesn't include `tlmgr` because Ubuntu wants all software incl. LaTeX packages to be installed over its own manager.

Comment: @Martin: I thought with the new Version of Ubuntu and TexLive it is possible. Thanks for the information.

Comment: @Macro: I don't now if it is now possible with Ubuntu 11.04. I have a manual installed TeXLive and didn't change that when I upgraded to 11.04.

Comment: @Martin: Ubuntu 11.04 doesn't include `tlmgr` (and it never will since that would contradict the idea of a system-wide package manager). Unfortunately Ubuntu 11.04 still includes TeX Live 2009.

Comment: @c089: I definitely recommend you get rid of TeXlive included in the distro and reinstall it from CTAN. I've done it, easy as pie, and been happy with it ever since.

Comment: Um, as Caramdir pointed out, it's TUG, not CTAN. My bad.

Comment: Actually, I like using official packages from Ubuntu for convenience and security reasons, that's what linux package management is all about. I don't understand why they don't include tlmgr though. They have e.g. python's easy_install and pip and ruby's gems which all install non-ubunutu, non-deb stuff.

Comment: @c089: Including `tlmgr` would cancel your security reasons (it also updates the tex binaries). It would actually update your whole installation, so that there wouldn't be much left from the Ubuntu/Debian packages.

Comment: In my case (Kubuntu 15.10) I managed to get mdframed by apt-getting `texlive-latex-extra`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The current Ubuntu 11.04 includes TeX Live 2009, which is a bit too old for the `mdframed` package. The Ubuntu installation also lacks the TeX Live Manager (`tlmgr`) so that you cannot install new packages automatically. So you have to install the package manually, e.g. from [CTAN](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mdframed).

Comment: Or install TeX Live directly from [TUG](http://tug.org/texlive/).

Comment: I am new in ubuntu, could someone explain how install mdframed, I use TeXLive-2009. or how to change TexLive 2009 to TexLive2011. tk :)